# Unresolved dependency in published assembly package in SBT

Tags: sbt, publish, sbt-assembly

In my project there are 3 sub projects under root. build.sbt is as below.
proj_C depends on proj_A and proj_B.
If I created the assembly proj_C package with below command. It success and the assembly package could be imported in other projects.

> sbt "project proj_C" assembly

If I publish with "sbt publish", as I defined addArtifact in proj_C settings, an assembly jar package is also generated and then published. But when I try to compile another project which imports this assembly jar, it will below error

> [error] unresolved dependency: proj_A;1.0.0: not found

part of build.sbt is as below. Could anyone point me what I made wrong in my way?
Many thanks!

```
artifact in (Compile, assembly) := {
  val art = (artifact in (Compile, assembly)).value
  art.withClassifier(Some("assembly"))
}

lazy val assemblySettings = Seq(
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case _ => MergeStrategy.first
    }
  }
)

lazy val root = Project(base = file("."))
  .disablePlugins(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin)
  .aggregate(proj_A, proj_B, proj_C)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    skip in publish := true,
    name := "proj_root"
  )

lazy val proj_A= (project in file("proj_A"))
  .disablePlugins(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    skip in publish := true,
    name := "proj_A"
  )

lazy val proj_B= (project in file("proj_B"))
  .disablePlugins(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    skip in publish := true,
    name := "proj_B"
  )

lazy val proj_C= (project in file("proj_C"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    addArtifact(artifact in (Compile, assembly), assembly),
    name := "proj_C"
  ) dependsOn(proj_A, proj_B)
```

Comment: Is "assembly" in this context actually talking about assembly language for machine code, like `mov eax, [rsi + rax*4]` (x86-64)?  There are separate tags for [tag:java-bytecode-asm] and [tag:.net-assembly], but I can't tell if those apply or if you're using SBT to build assembly-language projects.  Please fix the tags if necessary.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info).

Comment: should be sbt-assembly. sorry for the confusing. I'm using the sbt plugin for assembly: addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")

Comment: Found the cause but still no graceful solution. The assembly jar in publish is OK. But the .pom file which is along with the assembly jar defines the dependencies to proj_A and proj_B. So I need to find a way to customize the pom file when the assembly jar is generated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope you know that [the publishing of the fat jar is not recommended](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#publishing-not-recommended). And to be honest, in your case I really see no benefit in doing so.

If you simply publish `A`, `B`, `C` separately and then add the dependency in your other project it will all be automatically downloaded (along with dependencies of those projects). And the dependency management will be much easier...

---

**But**, since you want to add the `A-assembly` dependency, by the error I guess that you are actually adding the wrong `jar`. My guess would be that you publish both `C.jar` and `C-assembly.jar`, and you added the dependency like:

```
"your.organisation" %% "C" % "version"
```

but you should have:

```
"your.organisation" %% "C" % "version" classifier "assembly"
```

Comment: Agree try not to publish a fat jar. We provide service in proj_C so we don't want to expose A and B to customers. My finding now is that the assembly package C is generated correctly with "sbt publish". But the .pom file generated in the publish process define a dependency on project A. This is inside the publish process so I don't know if we have ways to change the behavior. My current workaround is to create a new project with source files from project A, B and C and publish this project (of course without assembly here). This is not a graceful way but it works.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the pom manually and checking if it could work?

Comment: have no access to write the file after it is generated and published :(

Comment: you have in your local `.m2`

Comment: I'm able to modify the local one but have no access to upload it to the repo :(

Comment: Modify locally, so you could check how it should look like and then we could try to see what to change in sbt to build it properly.

Comment: modified locally. but when I try to publish with "sbt publish", a new .pom file is generated then :( I'm not sure if there's a way to modify the behavior inside  "sbt publish"